# javascript/jQuery plugin for formatting radio buttons and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a javascript/jQuery plugin for custom formatting of form radio buttons and checkboxes.  There are many out there, but I'm trying to determine which ones are most used and fit the following criteria:

- up-to-date: e.g. works on phone, tablet and computer
- fully-customizable: i.e. user can skin, rather than picking from pre-rolled themes
- cross-platform: renders identically (as much as possible) across platforms and browsers
- full-functioning: e.g. works with keyboard input
- as light-weight as possible (small size): e.g. I don't need other form elements (although obviously, it doesn't matter if it does)

Comment: I don''t code raw JS, but, rather AngularJs. For that we have Angular bootstrap-UI https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ take a look & maybe it will convince you to move to Angular ;-) That plus two-way data-binding.  The point, however, is that it is based on Twitter's Bootsrap library http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ which is probably what you want. It has a good grid system which is responsive, with three main screen sizes supported.

Comment: This does use Bootstrap, but unfortunately I'm tied to given requirements, so Angular is not possible... however, I have been meaning to look into it ;-)

Comment: Then bootstrap can do; you will just have to use the docs. AngularJS is **well** worth looking at, especially for the two way data binding. If not on this project, maybe just for fun at home?